# VB.NET 2010 Express "NotSupportException" unhandled

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, csv

I've been working on a script, a windows console application, that reads a .CSV for a file-path and other various information and then using System.IO.File.Copy to copy the file to a new directory and give it a new name. The file's im working with are .WAV files. Essentially I take a peek at the .CSV provided, then grab the filepath from there, then rename the file using different columns from the .CSV with dot-notation. I.E. Acc.Date.Name.Type.wav.

However, I'm experiencing "NotSupportedException" error on the line that copies and create the new file. The sub message is "The given paths format is not supported." Now, I've fairly new to VB code, I' assuming right now that .WAV format is not supported.

I'm not sure what all to add, if anything is needed let me know.

Here is the script so far:

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim fileLine As String
        Dim aryTextFile() As String
        Dim objReader As New System.IO.StreamReader("C:\Temp\EDCallFilePaths.csv")

        Do While objReader.Peek() <> -1
            fileLine = fileLine & objReader.ReadLine() & vbNewLine
            aryTextFile = fileLine.Split(",")
            If Not aryTextFile(7) = "null" Then
                System.IO.File.Copy(aryTextFile(7), "C:\Temp\" & aryTextFile(0) & "." & aryTextFile(2) & "." & aryTextFile(3) & "." & aryTextFile(4) & "." & aryTextFile(5) & "." & aryTextFile(6) & ".wav")
                fileLine = ""
            End If
        Loop
    End Sub

End Module
```

I should note, column 7 is the filepath to the recording

Comment: you might try using `Path.Combine` instead & of & gluing & all that & together to make sure you wend up with a valid file path.  The inner exception/details usually tells more

Comment: Hello, so I found that the carriage return was added onto the end of the file path. I had to add two strings, one for holding the source and one for the target. With those, I used the .Replace() function to remove the carriage return from the paths. Currently looking up syntac for the Path.Combine now

Comment: I notice that `aryTextFile(1)` is not used - is that deliberate?

Comment: Andrew, yes, we have it in the .CSV as a "just-in-case" for when we need it, but right now it's not involved in the file name. I've corrected the error with the filepaths, just working on varying other issues. Should I create an answer, or will you @Plutonix?

Comment: Regarding the carriage return, you added it yourself when you appended `vbNewLine` to the result of your `ReadLine()` call.